# Add column to CSV with pandas (value of new column calculated from other columns)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV with the following columns...

```
YEAR    AWARD
2020    RECORD OF THE YEAR 
2020    SONG OF THE YEAR 
2019    RECORD OF THE YEAR
```

I want to create another column (`_id`) and the value of that column will be calculated from the existing columns:

```
YEAR    AWARD                 _id
2020    RECORD OF THE YEAR    2020_RECORD_OF_THE_YEAR
2020    SONG OF THE YEAR      2020_SONG_OF_THE_YEAR
2019    RECORD OF THE YEAR    2019_RECORD_OF_THE_YEAR
```

I'm creating a python script to open my existing csv and add the new column using pandas..

This is what I'm trying so far but its throwing an error..

```
data = pd.read_csv('awards.csv')
data['_id'] = (data.YEAR + ' ' + data.AWARD).str.replace(' ', '_')
```

Comment: Please add your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your YEAR column to strings before you can concatenate them to the AWARD values. One way to do that is:

```
data['_id'] = (data.YEAR.apply(str) + ' ' + data.AWARD).str.replace(' ', '_')
```

You could also specify the data types when you load the data (see the `dtype` parameter to [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)), or change just the YEAR column to string after the data is loaded.